# tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss not working in version 2.1 Is there any replacement I can use for it?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

```
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=global_step,
        learning_rate=params['lr'],
        optimizer=(params['optimizer']),
        update_ops=update_ops,
        clip_gradients=params['clip_gradients'],
        summaries=[
            "learning_rate",
            "loss",
            "global_gradient_norm",
        ]
    )
```

I am getting an error while using this in Tensorflow version 2.1
I was wondering if I can replace contrib with something else which can work for me.

> Error - AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it with optimize_loss in tf_slim.

```
import tf_slim as slim
train_op = slim.optimize_loss(...)
```

[Here is the link of github repository](https://github.com/google-research/tf-slim/blob/77b441267e27359e94a641b906f07afc25f69b13/tf_slim/layers/optimizers.py#L58)